# Running django developing server in a docker container

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

So I'm trying to run Django developing server on a container but I can't access it through my browser. I have 2 containers using the same docker network, one with postgress and the other is Django. I manage to ping both containers and successfully connect 2 of them together and run `./manage.py runserver` ok but can't `curl` or open it in a browser

Here is my Django docker file

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY ./requirements.txt .
ADD ./parking/ /parking
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps python3-dev gcc py3-pip postgresql-dev py3-virtualenv musl-dev libc-dev linux-headers 


RUN virtualenv /.env 
RUN /.env/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /parking
EXPOSE 8000 5432
```

The postgres container I pulled it from docker hub

I ran django with

`docker run --name=django --network=app -p 127.4.3.1:6969:8000 -it dev/django:1.0`

I ran postgres with

`docker run --name=some-postgres --network=app -p 127.2.2.2:6969:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -e POSTGRES_DB=parking postgres`

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: What URL did you access with curl or browser?

Comment: I access with ```Starting development server at http://127.1.9.9:8000/```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I manage to figure it out, I have looked at @leonardo-alves-dos-santos answer and I come to the conclusion that I run `CMD "python parking/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` . Now I can access my Django app with Django container port `127.4.3.1:6969` and `172.18.0.2:8000` from docker network

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add the command to run your application at the and of the dockerfile, when you run this image it just start the virtualenv and install all python dependencies at the requirements.txt, but the django application was not started. You need put at the end something like

```
CMD "python parking/manage.py runserver"
```

this will make your container still running at the choosed port and make you application accessible at 127.4.3.1:6969:8000.

Comment: I still can't access it mate browser said the connection was reset when I'm typing ```127.4.3.1:6969```